# Install nginx-1.20.2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nginx

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and i have installed nginx using sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx

But after installation when i do nginx -V to check version it always shows 1.18 version instead of latest version.

How i can install latest stable version of nginx on ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Your question is very valid, I don't know why the down vote.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to install [version 1.20.2 specifically](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/nginx-amd64/nginx_1.20.0-1%7Efocal_amd64.deb.html), you will need to add the official nginx repository to your Sources list.

Here is how you do it:

0. Open Terminal (or connect via SSH)
1. Ensure you have all of the prerequisites installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install curl gnupg2 ca-certificates lsb-release ubuntu-keyring
   ```
2. Import the nginx signing key for apt:

   ```
   curl https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | gpg --dearmor \
        | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
   ```
3. Create a sources `.list` file for apt:

   ```
   echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg] \
        http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` nginx" \
        | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
   ```
4. Pin the repository to ensure the nginx packages are installed instead of the Ubuntu-provided packages:

   ```
   echo -e "Package: *\nPin: origin nginx.org\nPin: release o=nginx\nPin-Priority: 900\n" \
        | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/99-nginx
   ```
5. Update apt:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
6. Install nginx:

   ```
   sudo apt install nginx
   ```

Comment: Working Perfect. Thanks